# Cast generic type to interface type constraint

Tags: c#, .net

Is is possible to make the following compile without:

1. Making `IFooCollection` generic
2. Explicitly implementing `IFooCollection.Items` on `FooCollection` and performing an       explicit cast.

---

```
public interface IFoo
{

}

public interface IFooCollection
{
    IEnumerable<IFoo> Items { get; }
}

public class FooCollection<T> : IFooCollection where T : IFoo
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I'm happy enough with the second solution (implementing the interface explicitly) but would like to understand why I need to cast `T` as `IFoo` when we have a generic constraint specifying that `T` must implement `IFoo`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is the following:

`IFooCollection.Items` can contain any class that implements `IFoo`. So it can contain `FooA`, `FooB`, `FooC` at the same time.

`FooCollection<FooA>.Items` on the other hand can only contain elements of type `FooA`. Trying to cast `FooB` or `FooC` to `FooA` would yield an `InvalidCastException` although all implement `IFoo`.